# Is it possible to run a server function in Nextjs 14 middleware.js and add the data to the request?

Tags: http, next.js, request, fetch-api, middleware

Currently, in my application, I require a server-side context (a more extensive version of the client context, containing sensitive information). I attempted to create and add it to the request through middleware. While I can obtain the session (using next-auth getToken) in the middleware, I am unable to import and execute my "getContext" function to generate a context based on the database information of the logged-in user. Is there a way to execute this function and append the context to all my requests using Next.js middleware?

I haven't been able to find a solution, and in most cases, people have mentioned that it's not possible to modify the request in middleware (to be used in route API, for example, with the GET method), only the header. I prefer not to include this type of information in the headers.